# Symfony2 : Multiple Upload File doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, symfony-forms

When I select two files, this code doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong..

This is my controller.

```
public function createAction()
{
  $router = $this->get('router');
  $request = $this->get('request');
  $description = $request->request->get('description');                                   
  $picturesFromPage = $request->files->all();                                             
  $jsonErrorCreator = $this->get('project_api.create_error_json');
  $nbPictures = count($picturesFromPage);                                                   

  return ($jsonErrorCreator->createErrorJson(101, $nbPictures));
}
```

In my twig:

```
<input name="pictures" type='file' multiple='multiple' required>
```

The Json answers:

```
{"code":101,"msg":"0 files uploaded","data":1}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you access `Request` object like that: `createAction(Request $request)`

Comment: If you var_dump `count($picturesFromPage)` what does it show?

Comment: it shows 1 for 2 selected items

Comment: @Gura I would recommend to set `$picturesFromPage = $request->files->get('pictures');` Also you need to put the name of file input in brackets if you want to upload multiple like `name="pictures[]"`

Comment: @Javad it works! So why $request->files->all() don't do this job?

Comment: Because `all()` returns all parameters of your form not the values in array; so for the `pictures` it will just return the "picture" parameter but if you use `get()` it will get all value(s); If you like I will make it as answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `files->all()` method returns all form parameters not the submitted value(s). It's better to use `files->get()` instead so that it will get the value(s) of the parameter you want.
Change it as:

```
$picturesFromPage = $request->files->get('pictures');
```

Furthermore, if you want to submit an array of values in your form you need to put their name in bracket as

```
<input name="pictures[]" type='file' multiple='multiple' required>
```